# Опенкарт - вывести в карточке товара список фильтров

Tags: opencart, фильтр

Есть такая полезная фишка в опенкарт 2 - фильтры. 
Каждому товару назначаются фильтры в разделе связи. 
А как вывести **на фронте в карточке товара** те фильтры, которые ему назначены?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В файле модели `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` определите новый метод:

```
public function getProductFilter($product_id){

    $query = "SELECT pf.product_id, fd.filter_group_id, fgd.name as `filter_group_name`, pf.filter_id, fd.name as `filter_name`
      FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "_product_filter pf
      JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "_filter_description fd ON pf.filter_id = fd.filter_id
      JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "_filter_group_description fgd ON fgd.filter_group_id = fd.filter_group_id
      WHERE product_id = " . $product_id . " AND fgd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "
      ORDER BY filter_group_name";

    $this->db->query($query);

    return $this->rows;

}
```

В файле контроллера товара вызовите новый метод модели:

```
$data['product_filters'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductFilter($product_id);
```

В файле представления разверните массив с данными о фильтрах:

```
foreach($product_filters as $filter){
    // $filter['filter_group_name'] -имя группы фильтров
    // $filter['filter_name'] -имя фильтра
}
```

написано на коленке, но должно работать =)

Comment: Пожалуй, наиболее разжеванный ответ за всю историю SO! Спасибо, тестирую.

Answer (score 2):

Потратил 4 часа и смог реализовать наконец!

вывести в карточке товара список фильтров Opencart 3

Файл:

> catalog/controller/product/category.php

Перед:

> 'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],

*Приблизительно 198 строчка*

Поставить следующий кусок кода:

> 'filter_groups' =>
>   $this->model_catalog_product->getProductFilters($result['product_id']),

Файл:

> catalog/model/catalog/product.php

Перед:

> public function getTotalProductSpecials()

Поставить следующий кусок кода:

```html
public function getProductFilters($product_id){
  
  $product_filter_group_data = array();
  $sql = "SELECT fg.filter_group_id, fgd.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter pf LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "filter f ON (pf.filter_id = f.filter_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_group fg ON (f.filter_group_id = fg.filter_group_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_group_description fgd ON (fg.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id) WHERE pf.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND fgd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' GROUP BY fg.filter_group_id ORDER BY fg.sort_order, fgd.name";
  $product_filter_group_query = $this->db->query($sql);
  
  foreach ($product_filter_group_query->rows as $product_filter_group) {
    $product_filter_data = array();
    
    $product_filter_query = $this->db->query("SELECT f.filter_id, fd.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter pf LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "filter f ON (pf.filter_id = f.filter_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "filter_description fd ON (f.filter_id = fd.filter_id) WHERE pf.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND f.filter_group_id = '" . (int)$product_filter_group['filter_group_id'] . "' AND fd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY f.sort_order, fd.name");
    
    foreach ($product_filter_query->rows as $product_filter) {
      $product_filter_data[] = array(
      'filter_id' => $product_filter['filter_id'],
      'name'         => $product_filter['name']
      );
    }
    
    $product_filter_group_data[] = array(
    'filter_group_id' => $product_filter_group['filter_group_id'],
    'name'               => $product_filter_group['name'],
    'filter'          => $product_filter_data
    );
  }
  
  return $product_filter_group_data;
}
```

Файл:

> catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.twig

После

> {{ product.description }}

Поставить следующий кусок кода:

```html
{% if product.filter_groups %}
<div class="filter">
  {% for filter_group in product.filter_groups %} 
  {% for filter in filter_group.filter %} 
  <div>{{ filter.name }}</div>
  {% endfor %}                    
  {% endfor %} 
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Я про двойку спрашивал. Но все равно пригодится, спасибо